# How do you connect the following topologies on $X_1 \times X_2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i)The product topology on $X_1 \times X_2$ which has it's subbasis all the elements of the form $\pi^{-1}(U_{i})$ where $U_{i}$ is open in $X_{i}$

ii)The box topology which has its basis elements sets of the form $U_1 \times U_2$ where $U_1$ is a basis of $X_1$ and $U_2$ is a basis of $X_2$

iii)Let $d_1,d_2$ be two metrics in $X_1 \times X_2$ then $d$ defined on $X_1 \times X_2$ is $d(x,y) = \max\{d_1(x_1,y_1),d_2(x_2,y_2)\}$(product metric).Here I proved that the topology formed by the metric $d$ has basis of the form $B_d((x,y);r)$ where $B_d((x,y);r) = B_{d_1}(x;r) \times B_{d_2}(y;r)$ .

Are there any links in between them?Also the intuition behind product topology is not at all clear to me. How do we suddenly come up with such a definition..

**Edit 1**:I did go through the difference between product topology and box topology in munkres but what I don't understand is whether there is a connection between the topology induced by the product metric and product topology(both for finite and infinite cases)

My confusion is in the idea:

The basis of the topology under the product metric has basis of the form $B_d((x,y);r)$. Also I have shown that it is the same as the topology induced by the basis elements of the form $B_{d_1}(x;r) \times B_{d_2}(y;r)$ .Also $B_{d_1}(x;r)$ is a basis of $X_1$ and $B_{d_2}(x;r)$ is a basis of $X_2$.

So the basis elements of the space $X_1 \times X_2$ are of the form $B_1 \times B_2$ where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are the basis of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Isn't this like box topology?

Comment: The product topology is the minimal topology necessary to make the projection functions continuous. This has been discussed on this site a lot. Googling product vs. box topology will probably yield a lot of results that will make the difference between them clear. For finite products spaces, there is no difference.

Comment: I did go through the difference between product topology and box topology in munkres but what I don't understand is whether there is a connection between the topology induced by the product metric and product topology(both for finite and infinite cases)

Comment: For the product of finitely many spaces the box topology and the product topology coincide, and they are metrizable if and only if either all the spaces are metrizable or one of them is empty. The procedure that you have described produces a metric that accomplishes such feat.

Comment: So if I consider an infinite product of metric spaces of the form $X_i$ where $i =1 (2) \infty$ and I consider the product metric $d((x,y)) = \max\{d_1(x_1,y_1),d_2(x_2,y_2),\cdots d_n(x_n,y_n) , \cdots \}$ then will I be able to show that the topology generated by $B_d(x;r)$ and by $\{B_{d_1}(x_1;r) \times B_{d_n}(x_n;r)..\}$ are not equal?

Comment: The "product metric" you give is not quite well-defined yet, there is no reason for the maximum of an infinite set of numbers to exist. Any functional definition of the product metric you can give will produce the product topology, though. The box topology is in general not first-countable, hence not metrizable in any way.